# wrong in (master) hdfs dfsadmin -report ,it display all is 0

Tags: hadoop, centos7

like follows:

![enter image description here][1]

jps at the namenode(hadoop1):

```
5965 SecondaryNameNode
```

`5688 NameNode`

```
6190 ResourceManager
```

jps at the datanode(hadoop2):

```
6498 DataNode
```

jps at the datanode(hadoop3):

```
3035 DataNode
```

1.namenode can ssh datanodes ,in return datanodes can ssh namenode ,each datanodes can ssh each others

2.master(hadoop1)

/etc/hostname

```
hadoop1
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.120.191 hadoop1
192.168.120.192 hadoop2
192.168.120.193 hadoop3
```

datanode(hadoop2):
/etc/hostname

```
hadoop2
```

/etc/hosts
like the master

Comment: I have stop the iptable,the three system can ping each others    and  i have chmod -R 777 to the hadoop home. When in the datanode(hadoop2),hdfs dfsadmin -report ,its return report: No Route to Host from  hadoop2/192.168.120.192 to hadoop1:9000 failed on socket timeout exception: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: 没有到主机的路由; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/NoRouteToHost

Comment: hadoop 2.6.0jdk 1.7.0_75   the OS is centos 7 in the VirtualBox use Bridged Adapter  hdfs-site.xml is  <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>/home/xiaoyu/hadoop-2.6.0/namenodedir,/home/xiaoyu/hadoop-2.6.0/namenodedirbak</value>
    </property>
<property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>/home/xiaoyu/hadoop-2.6.0/datanodedir,/home/xiaoyu/hadoop-2.6.0/datanodedirbak</value>
    </property>

Comment: the picture above not display it is this:Configured Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Present Capacity: 0 (0 B)
DFS Remaining: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used%: NaN%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0

Answer (score 0):

centos7 should be use `systemctl stop firewalld` to stop the firewalld ,rather than sysytemctl stop iptables..........